# ActionScript. Passing vector by reference or value?

Tags: actionscript, pass-by-reference

I am trying to port some ActionScript code to VB.Net.

AS code:

```
public class GridHandler extends Object {
    private var grid:Vector.<Vector.<Tile>>;
    private var config:Config;

    public function GridHandler(param1:Config, param2:Vector.<Vector.<Tile>>) {
        this.config = param1;
        this.grid = param2;
        return;
    }// end function
```

are the values param1 and param2 passed by reference or value?
It sure looks like they are being passed by reference, but I need to be sure.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS3, everything is passed by reference - even primitives like `ints` and `Numbers` (though they have special operators behinds the scenes to make them act like pass-by-value.

Short answer to your question: yes :)

Link to the relevant docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56__WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f4c